# MySQL- Update column with same id from different table by combining its values with same id

Tags: mysql

### TableA

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

### TableB

| id | number2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

I want to trigger update the TableB whenever TableA is updated.

Result should be

### TableB

| id | number2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0,1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0,1,2 |

The following statement display the result

```
select `id`, 
       group_concat(`number` separator ',') 
from TableA 
group by `id`
```

but I want to trigger update the TableB whenever TableA is updated.
(Optional): Only update the id which is updated will be preferred.

New workaround

```
CREATE TRIGGER `store_jan` AFTER UPDATE ON `TableA` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE  `TableB`
    SET number2 = group_concat(`number` separator ',') from TableA group by `id`
    WHERE `TableB`.`id` = `TableA`.`id`
END
```

But showing error
Please help

Comment: You could just create a view based on your query instead of creating a separate table for the same data.

Comment: Table A and Table B both are existing tables in the database.

Comment: Replace table B with a view, problem solved.

Comment: "Showing an error", is it? Please [edit] your question to show us the error message.

Comment: Really really Bad Idea